# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data-angular 2

Tags: json, angular

When i post data to my server , i get this error in my database " SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Learn More]" but anyway the data still goes into the database. What could be there error?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably server returned error page (which is not valid JSON), check response in network tab in developer tools.